# Lisp program (using Scheme 48 1.9 interpreter) to find out the sum of series 1^3 + 2^3 + …. + n^3

Tags: scheme, lisp

Turn in your work as a single plain text file, containing SCHEME code that defines all the necessary functions, before midnight of the due date.

LISP Programming

1. Write a Lisp function sumcubes which takes a number n and return the sum 1*1*1 + 2*2*2 + ... + n*n*n. eg:

(sumcubes 0)

0

(sumcubes 4) 100

(because 13 + 23 + 33 + 43 = 1 + 8 + 27 + 64 = 100)

I've seen how to do this in C, and I'm having trouble with formatting it in LISP.

Thanks in advance for your help (I barely know LISP, and I basically have a week to learn it).

This is the stuff from the C code that I saw (http://www.cquestions.com/2011/07/write-c-program-to-find-out-sum-of_19.html):

> Sum of 1^2 + 2^2 + …. + n^2 series in c programming language

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int n,i;
int sum=0;

printf("Enter the n i.e. max values of series: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

sum = (n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1 )) / 6; //I believe this is the crucial line I need.

printf("Sum of the series : ");

for(i =1;i<=n;i++){
     if (i != n)
         printf("%d^2 + ",i);
     else
         printf("%d^2 = %d ",i,sum);
}

return 0;
}
```

> Sample output:
>
> Enter the n i.e. max values of series: 5
>   Sum of the series: 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 = 55
>
> Mathematical Formula:
>
> Sum of the series 12 + 22 + 32 + … + n2 =
>   n (n+1) (2n+1)/6

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this question myself.

```
> (define (sumcubes n) (expt (/ (* (+ 1 n) n) 2) 2))
; no values returned
> (sumcubes 3)
36
> (sumcubes 4)
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Give us some sort of code, even if it's just in C. I'm totally newb at C, so here goes some puedo-C. Translation to scheme is still left up to you.

I'm assuming your thinking something like

```
sumcube{INT n} {
    INT acc = 0
    for i<n, i++ , 1 {
    acc = acc + cube(i)
    }
    return acc}
```

The most straightforward scheme is going to be fairly similar. Instead initializing an accumulator and manipulating its value in a for loop, you define a helper procedure (function) that takes an n and some accumulator value directly as arguments. It also helps to work down to 1 instead of up (work towards a base case)

```
sumcube{INT n}{
  return sumecubehelper(n 0)}

sumcubehelper {INT n, INT acc}{
    if i<1 
    return acc
    else sumcumbehelper(n - 1 , acc + cube(n))}
    acc = acc + cube(i)
    }
    return acc}
```

You can also use higher order functions like map, apply, fold and so on, but most issues can be expressed though explicit recursion.